# How to pass hashtables / objects from template to runbooks

Tags: json, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have written a template and accompanying runbook. The template triggers the runbook. The template and the runbook are working fine, until I try and pass an object to one of the runbook's parameters. The Azure error is:

#### Error

```
"content":  
{
    "status":  "Failed",
    "error":  
    {
        "code":  "DeploymentFailed",
        "message":  "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
        "details":
        [
            {
                "code":  "BadRequest",
                "message":  "{\r\n  \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"message\": \"{\\\"Message\\\":\\\"The request is invalid.\\\",\\\"ModelState\\\":{\\\"job.properties.parameters.MyTags\\\":[\\\"An error has occurred.\\\"]}}\"\r\n}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is meant by `ModelState`, however the `job.properties.parameters.MyTags` is pointing to the troublesome parameter.

I am sure it is something to do with the datatype. It may be because the parameter is being passed as a JSON object and the runbook cannot understand it. I'm more used to passing objects from PowerShell to templates.

#### Runbook (Update-ResourceGroupTags.ps1)

For testing, the runbook looks like:

```
param
(
    [string]$ResourceGroupId,
    $MyTags
)
Write-Output "ResourceGroupId: $ResourceGroupId"
Write-Output "MyTags: $($MyTags | Out-String)"
Write-Output "MyTagsType: $($MyTags.GetType() | Out-String)"
```

No authentication as it's not required yet and I have deliberately not typed `$MyTags`, although I have tried `[object]` and using `[parameter(Mandatory = $true)] just in case there's an unwritten  / missed rule.

### Goal

In brief, I create a complex object as a variable in the template and I want to pass it to a runbook's parameter as a single object. The values are dynamic and not known until deploy-time. Having to specify each parameter (test 8) in the runbook breaks this requirement.

I start a template with the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet.

I create a "complex object" variable:

```
"rolesTagObject": {
   "db": "TestVm1",
   "Server": "TestVm1",
   "Client": "TestVm1"
}
```

The template runs a resource of `"type" : "jobs"`.

The Runbook, run by `jobs` has a parameter `MyTags` which needs to take `roleTagObject` which I pass to `jobs.properties.parameters.MyTags` thus:

```
,
"parameters": {
     "MyTags": "[variable('roleTagObject')]"
}
```

This is what's not working. If I break it down into each key (Test 8) it works.

My initial thought is to convert it to a single string and pass it to the runbook using `json()` function, but I don't know of a way to do that in a template.

#### Template (testRunRunbook.json)

I've put the template in a GIST so as not to make this question any longer.
https://gist.github.com/arcotek-ltd/7c606540980a45a3a7915ccae2e0b140

The template has been written so I can copy out the `"resources":[]` section into a different template. Hence why some variables and parameters may appear to be oddly named. As I said, the template works, apart from this issue.

#### PowerShell

I am calling the template with PowerShell, thus:

```
$Ticks = (Get-Date).Ticks.ToString()
$RGID = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "MyResourceGroup").ResourceId

$MyTags = @{"TestTag2"="TestValue2"}

$JsonTagsHash = ($MyTags | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Out-String) -replace '\s',''

$TemplateParametersObject = @{
    currentDateTimeInTicks = $Ticks
    runbookParameters = @{
        ResourceGroupId = $RGID
        #"MyTags" = $MyTags #$JsonTagsHash
    } 
}

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
        -Name "Test_Runbook" `
        -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" `
        -Mode Incremental `
        -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All `
        -Force `
        -TemplateFile "D:temp\testRunRunbook.json" `
        -Verbose `
        -TemplateParameterObject $TemplateParametersObject
```

---

I've tried the following tests:

#### Test 1

Uncomment `$TemplateParametersObject.runbookParameters.MyTags`:

```
$MyTags = @{"TestTag1"="TestValue1"}

$TemplateParametersObject = @{
    currentDateTimeInTicks = $Ticks
    runbookParameters = @{
        ResourceGroupId = $RGID
        MyTags = $MyTags
    } 
}
```

Result **Fail** - See error above.

---

#### Test 2

Replace `$MyTags` with `$JsonTagsHash`:

```
$MyTags = @{"TestTag2"="TestValue2"}

$JsonTagsHash = ($MyTags | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Out-String) -replace '\s',''

$TemplateParametersObject = @{
    currentDateTimeInTicks = $Ticks
    runbookParameters = @{
        ResourceGroupId = $RGID
        MyTags = $JsonTagsHash
    } 
}
```

Result: **PASS** Works as expected. Parameters are passed to runbook.

---

Test 2 works, but I need to be able to pass the parameters to the runbook that are generated inside the template at runtime. In other words, I can't use PowerShell. Inside the template at `job.properties.parameters` (Line 103 in the gist)

#### Test 3

To prove it's `MyTags` causing the issue, take it out completely:

```
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroupId": "[parameters('runbookParameters').ResourceGroupId]"
}
```

Result: **No error**, however, `myTags` are not passed (obviously).

---

#### Test 4

Create a variable object and pass that to the parameter:

```
"variables" : {
    "rolesTagObject": {
        "db": "TestVm1",
        "Server": "TestVm1",
        "Client": "TestVm1"
    }
}
```

And back in `job.properties.parameters`:

```
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroupId": "[parameters('runbookParameters').ResourceGroupId]",
    "MyTags": "[variables('rolesTagObject')]"
}
```

Result **Fail** - See error above.

---

#### Test 5

Try directly:

```
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroupId": "[parameters('runbookParameters').ResourceGroupId]",
    "MyTags": {
         "testTag5" : "testValue5"
    }
}
```

Result **Fail** - See error above.

---

#### Test 6

Use the `json()` [template function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#json). Not that I expect it to work as it needs a string.

```
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroupId": "[parameters('runbookParameters').ResourceGroupId]",
    "MyTags": "[json(variables('rolesTagObject'))]"
}
```

Result **Fail**. As predicted:

```
'The template language function 'json' expects an argument of type 'string'. The provided value is of type 'Object'.
```

---

#### Test 7

Try with the example provided my MS for `json()` [template function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#json):

```
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroupId": "[parameters('runbookParameters').ResourceGroupId]",
    "MyTags": "[json('{\"a\": \"b\"}')]"
}
```

Result **Fail**- See error above. Interesting! But why? The working PowerShell test suggests it needs to be a JSON object. Is this not what `json()` does?

---

#### Test 8

Breaking out the object into individual key / values:

```
"parameters": {
    "db": "[variables('rolesTagObject').db]",
    "server": "[variables('rolesTagObject').server]",
    "client": "[variables('rolesTagObject').client]"
                }
```

I also have to change the parameters in the runbook from one to three.

Result **Pass** - but the idea of being able to pass an object is that it can have any number of key / value pairs. This way, not only does the variable and parameter have to be hardcoded, so does the runbook. Not very flexible.

---

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The automation job parameters does not understand complex objects so you would want to pass in the parameter as a string and then convert back to Json within your runbook.
In your example, you could put quotes around the json object $MyTags so that it comes through as a string.

From

```
$TemplateParametersObject = @{
    currentDateTimeInTicks = $Ticks
    runbookParameters = @{
        ResourceGroupId = $RGID
        "MyTags" = $MyTags
    } 
}
```

to

```
$TemplateParametersObject = @{
    currentDateTimeInTicks = $Ticks
    runbookParameters = @{
        ResourceGroupId = $RGID
        "MyTags" = "$MyTags"
    } 
}
```

Then inside your runbook you could do 
$MyTags = ConvertFrom-Json $MyTags

to get it back to a json object that you can use as needed.

If you are converting an object inside a template to a string, then you can just use the string function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#string

Example as shown in the comments:

```
"myParams": {
  "Hello": "World",
  "Location": {
    "Country": "USA",
    "State": "WA"
  }
},
```

and then you can pass in this template object by just converting it to a string:

```
 "properties": {
"runbook": {
    "name": "[variables('runbookName')]"
},
"parameters": {
    "ResourceGroupId": "[variables('myParams').Hello]",
    "MyTags": "[String(variables('myParams'))]"
}
```

If the string function doesn't work, please let me know.

Hope this help,
Eamon

Comment: Thanks @Eamon, but that's PowerShell. I need to 'convert' an object to a string inside a template.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by object inside a template? Looking at your example, it seems you have an something like:     "myParams": {
      "Hello": "World",
      "Location": {
        "Country": "USA",
        "State": "WA"
      } and it seems you could call this like                     "parameters": {
                      "ResourceGroupId": "[variables('myParams').Hello]",
                      "MyTags": "[String(variables('myParams').Location)]"
                    } by just converting it to a string with the String function? I might be missing something here though. Thanks

Comment: I've added an 'Goal' section and Test 8 to the question and modified the gist template (job.properties.paramaters.MyTag). Hopefully that makes it clearer. Thank you.